# Patent Attorney Free Online Consultation?

Tags: legal, micro-entity

I have a unique question concerning the financial provisions and restrictions of micro-entity filing status.  I have been unable to find an answer to my question online, and would like to ask a patent attorney.  However, the free consultation services that I have found specifically offer advice regarding individual inventions or claims, which is not the subject of my inquiry.  Where can I find free online consultation with a patent attorney (preferably via email) for more general questions such as mine?  Thank you.

Comment: If you want to ask the question on this site you may get an answer. Patent attorneys do read these questions.

Comment: @EricShain is correct: this site is almost certainly your best bet. Otherwise, patent attorneys (and indeed any professionals) are unlikely to work for free for a one-off query with no reasonable expectation of future paid work: that is just bad business.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking if somebody that invested a lot in their education would be willing to explain to you in detail how to not pay them for their job. 
Do you see the problem?

Sites like this can help you with specific questions, but if you need a lot of information, either start learning or pay a patent attorney ;-).

Comment: No, that is not what I am asking.  I have a question concerns micro entity filing status and application fees, not legal fees.